# Convert WebView to UIWebView

Tags: printing, webview, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I want to print a webview with the Tsp 100 lan printer functionalities which are available on both Android and iOS. I have a DependencyService with a Print method, which calls the platform specific code to access the printing functionalities. The problem is that I am not able to convert WebView to UIWebView or UIImage. Any one know how to convert webview to UIWebView or webview to direct UIImage?

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom webview and invoke your print event

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/